# Swift: formatting NSDictionary as JSON with specific date format

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdateformatter

Is there a way in Swift to specify a specific date format for `NSDate` object?

For example, if I have an `NSDictionary` with `NSDate` objects, and would like this JSON:

```
{
  "something": [{
    "something_else": [{
      "data": {
        "total": 117,
        "updateTime": "2016-06-07T05:26:52-0300",
        "endTime": "2016-06-07T08:26:52-0300",
        "startTime": "2016-06-06T08:26:52-0300",
        "dayRangeBars": [{
          "belowRange": 36,
          "aboveRange": 5
        }]
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Does `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject` have a way of specifying the date format?

Comment: Have you try NSDateFormatter. Also put some code of your.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to stringify the date your self

Example:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
var dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(YourNSDateInstanceHERE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. There are some libraries out there that can do this -- [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle) is probably the most well-known one.  There is also this: https://github.com/jagill/JAGPropertyConverter